# how to relate models effectively using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an application to keep the accounts of a store. Each time an invoice is uploaded to the system it must create the products in another table called "products" but if the product already exists, only the price and quantity must be updated.

**Each invoice can have several products**

1. How should I propose the relationship between the tables?. One to many, one to one, many to many?
2. Is there any way to represent the relationship in a way that creates a list of products on each invoice?. A supplier can bring more than one product.
3. Is there a way in which you can create the records in the product table without creating duplicates?. It is not necessary to have the same product more than once if the price and quantity in the inventory were updated when entering a new invoice.

For example, the invoice to be entered has the following information:

- Number
- List item
- Provider
- Products: (list)

  - Product a
  - Product b
  - Product c
- Total
- Date

If product A exists, the invoice must update the price and quantity in the inventory.

If product C does not exist, the invoice must create the product.

Until now, this is what I have:

**invoice/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

from product.models import Product
from sales.models import PaymentMethod


class Supplyer(models.Model):
    """
    Proveedor de servicios o productos
    """

    rif = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.name, self.rif)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    """
    Clase que controla las facturas ingresadas al sistema
    """

    ref = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplyer = models.OneToOneField(Supplyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    paymnet_method = models.OneToOneField(PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.supplyer, self.date, self.ref)
```

**invoice/serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from invoice.models import Supplyer, Invoice
from stock.models import Product
from stock.serializers import ProductSerializer


class SupplyerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Clase que controla los proveedores de productos o servicios
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Supplyer
        fields = ('rif', 'name', 'phone', 'email')


class InvoiceSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Clase que controla las facturas de proveedores.

    Esta clase tiene un metodo crear propio para poder crear productos cuando
    se carga la factura, y si el producto ya existe, debe actualizar el costo
    del producto en el inventario
    """

    # Llamada al serializador de productos
    product_serializer = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    # Llamada al serializador de proveedores
    supplyer_serializer = SupplyerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('ref', 'supplyer_serializer', 'product_serializer', 'total', 'payment_method', 'date')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Este metodo sobre escribe el metodo de crear instancia por defecto del
        serializador, esto nos permite crear un producto y actualizar el
        precio al momento de cargar la factura al sistema.

        self: llamada al metodo
        validated_data: Datos validados por el serializador
        """

        # lista de productos o servicios en la factura
        products_obj = validated_data.pop('items')

        # Cargar la factura a la base de datos
        invoice = Invoice.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Iterar por la lista de productos de la factura
        for product in products_obj:
            Product.objects.create(products_obj)

        return invoice

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Este metodo actualiza las facturas y productos asociados a ella

        self: llamada al metodo
        instance: instancia u objeto a modificar
        validated_data: datos validados por el serializador
        """

        # Se obtienen los datos de los productos en la factura
        products_obj = validated_data.pop('items')
        products = (instance.product_serializer).all()
        products = list(products)

        # Se selecciona la factura y se actualizan los datos
        instance.ref = validated_data.get('ref', instance.ref)
        instance.supplyer = validated_data.get('supplyer', instance.supplyer)
        instance.total = validated_data.get('total', instance.total)
        instance.payment_method = validated_data.get('payment_method', instance.payment_method)

        # Iterar pro la lista de productos
        for product_data in products_obj:
            # Dentro del bucle se atualizan los datos de los productos
            product = products.pop(0)
            product.name = product_data.get('name', product.name)
            product.description = product_data.get('description', product.description)
            product.price = product_data.get('price', product.price)
            product.save()

        return instance
```

**stock/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)


class Stock(models.Model):
    item    = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete='CACADE')
    package = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unity   = models.IntegerField()
    date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    value   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    cost   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    qty     = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need another model to represent the line items of an invoice, including quantity and price.  For example, if Invoice 1 includes 50kg of bricks and 100kg of cement, then Invoice 2 has 20kg of bricks and 20kg of cement, how do you want to keep track of both records?

In your current models, the product "bricks" can be linked to both Invoice 1 and Invoice 2, but there is no place to store the different quantities of bricks listed on each invoice.

If you store the invoice line items in a separate model, it would have a ForeignKey field to the invoice, and another ForeignKey field to the product, along with fields for quantity and price.  When you have a specific invoice, you can [follow the relationship backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) to get its line items.

Comment: In this case I would be creating a table with repeated values, say that one invoice enters 100 blocks and another invoice 50, then it would have 2 records in that table, the first with 100 blocks and the second with 50 blocks. My question is what kind of relationship the invoice table should have with respect to the product table so that when creating an invoice it is updating the product instead of creating a new one, I don't know if this is the right thing or if I should create a table with repeated products and update the sales table with respect to that table

Comment: I don't think I understand your question very well, especially the part about "so that when creating an invoice it is updating the product instead of creating a new one". Here is a [inventory database structure diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755733/115246) from a different question. In addition to its "product" table and its "order" table, it has a "product_order" table, which is what I mean about representing the line items of the invoice.

Comment: In this case it should be a many-to-many relationship, an invoice has several products and with that invoice the quantity and value of the products are calculated. But how do I prevent an invoice from creating several records of the same article? And excuse my English, but it's not my language. (Should I send the diagram of the databases?) @krubo

Comment: Sure, if you have a structure diagram, you can add it to your question. Also maybe you can explain a specific example, like, if the user enters {example}, here's how the system should respond?